# Recursion with IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, recursion, try-catch, nodes, traversal

So I'm trying to write a preorder traversal method. I'm using my own nodes that have multiple child nodes. To keep track of them, each node has an array of children. When trying to traverse the map of the nodes recursively, I run into an IndexOutOfBoundsException which kills the program rather than just checking it as a null value can continuing. I've done my best to catch it with a try block but the way I have it put together right now, the method only traverses the first child in each child array.

Here's my code:

```
private void traverse (Node root) {
    peggyPoints.add(root);
    int i = 0;
    if (root.nexts != null) {
        try {
            Node current = root.nexts.get(i);
            while (current != null) {
                traverse(current);
                current = current.nexts.get(i+1);
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { }   
    }
}
```

peggyPoints is an arrayList used to keep track of the nodes visited. nexts is the array of children for the given node.

Given a map of

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \   \
  4   5   6
```

The visited nodes should be 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6 but with what I have it only visits 1, 2, 4.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think the approach you should be taking is to add a peg for the current node, then traverse *both* left and right recursively.  The line of code which stands out as being logically wrong is:

```
current = current.nexts.get(i+1);
```

I think you should be using `root` again to obtain the next node for traversal, i.e.

```
current = root.nexts.get(i+1);
```

But rather than even doing this, you can just use a for in loop with your `nexts` list and do away with managing the loop indices altogether:

```
private void traverse (Node root) {
    peggyPoints.add(root);

    if (root.nexts != null) {
        for (Node current : root.nexts) {
            traverse(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the edit.  Actually, the presence of the try catch for index out of bounds is a sign of bad design IMO.